# how to access remote windows SQL Server Express from Ubuntu VS C# Code

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code, sql-server-express, ubuntu-20.04

I have two PC's standing next to each other, both connected to the same wifi router for internet. One is windows with SQL Server Express, the other Ubuntu with  Visual Studio Code and my C# application.

I want to be able to communicate or access the SQL Server database from my application on the Ubuntu PC.

I can ping the windows PC with it's IP address from the Ubuntu PC.

And I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver15) tutorial successfully up until this line:

```
On a second computer that contains the SQL Server client tools,
```

Which I can't see that I can install on Ubuntu, what is the correct way of making the connection, or a simpler way?

EDIT:

**As according to the tutorial, steps taken:**

1. Enabled TCP/IP in Configuration Manager (SQL Server Network Configuration)
2. Added a fixed port to the TCP/IP under "IPALL, TCP Port" and restarted the service - SQL Server Network Configuration.(since it is SQL Express listens on dynamic ports and therefore won't work the next day)
3. Opened/ added that fixed port with a new Windows Firewall inbound rule

Comment: Have you opened port 1433 on the windows machine filewall to allow connections to sql server?

Comment: yes, as according to the MSDN tutorial linked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a client tool provided by Microsoft called mssql-cli (it is also available for Windows and can be used the same way). To install it, follow this quick guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu

After installation you are able to use mssql-cli. This page explains the usage in detail:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5298/new-interactive-command-line-tool-mssqlcli-for-sql-server/

Comment: That seems to be a command line tool only, an enhancement to query via the command line... does not seem to be the same thing. Also, the link then says to open Management Studio - I have no SQL software installed on my ubuntu PC, and if it is not needed, it would rather avoid to install

Comment: There is really no other way to validate that your sql server is reachable because ubuntu does not have any built in sql client features. Could you also please check 2.) on this link: https://docs.sdl.com/801922/570899/sdl-tridion-docs-13-sp2/microsoft-sql-server-ports ? This is also a common step to forget after installation.

Comment: I added the steps in my question which I completed, it covers check 2 as well. I then presume I should install SQL Server Express and Management Studio on my Ubuntu PC?  Then, is your link with command line tools the correct "SQL Server Client Tools" referred to in the tutorial?

Comment: If you continue to try to connect to the SQL Server on Windows, it is sufficient to install the Management Studio (or mssql-cli). You don't have to install a complete SQL Server Express on Ubuntu. Could you also try to allow port 1433 on your Ubuntu system? `sudo ufw allow 1443/tcp`

Comment: I installed mssql-cli at your supplied link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu). I did stop at the optional point 4 to note.  I guess I can add 1433, though it seems I have to use a fixed port for my windows sql server express, and I believe I have to use this connection string in visual studio code(C#):  "integrated security=SSPI;data source=<ip>:<port>;persist security info=false;initial catalog=<database>"

Comment: Do you know how to compete the step in mssql-cli in [the](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver15) tutorial at "To connect to the database engine from another computer", that the tutorial completes using Management Studio?

Comment: So if you properly installed the mssql-cli you can call `mssql-cli --help` in your terminal. This is a example to connect: `mssql-cli -S yourserver,1443 -d DataSource -U sa`

Comment: seems like I did something wrong, "command not found" when I run mssql-cli --help, and no suggestions given either with the error. The link I followed to install seemed to install good. In sources.list, these are the microsoft references there are:
sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main
sources.list.d/msprod.list:deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main
And another that seems clear that it is the vs code package, seems like it is not installed at all?  install again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234638/discussion-between-allstar-and-philipp-ape).